# How do you defeat Harold Godwinson in the William the Bastard campaign?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I read that if I wait a bit, Harold goes to fight Harald on Stamford bridge and gets messed up in the process. Yet all that happens is that the guy just keeps attacking me, totally ignoring Harald. Why?

Also, any tips on how to overcome this? Harold seems to have too many troops in my experience - sending an army of 14k after I repelled an invasion by his 3k army in Rouen.

Comment: Could you be more specific on where your lands are and where the battles are happening? I play CKII, but I don't know the "bastard campaign" and all of its actors by heart. (I'm pretty sure that the wars aren't scripted, though.)

Comment: I meant the William the Bastard/Conqueror one. Generally, the only way I see to win is if Harold Godwinson, king of England, goes to fight the other claimant, Harald Haardrada, the Norwegian king. Except he doesn't and from what I saw from 3 attempts, Harald doesn't even attack him seriously.

Comment: Are the Vikings actually invading England? It does sound odd that Harald is just sitting on the sidelines. When I last played as William (over a year ago), it did work out as you expected - once I learned to wait, Harald would eventually show up; whoever won, I took out the survivor. (Note that in that scenario, you start with an army much larger than you can normally raise. If you dismiss your army, you won't be able to get one that size again.)

Comment: I started out with around 9k men. I waited around two years, suffering many attacks, which I generally beat off, but lost most of my army.

Comment: Have you tried posting some tiny fleets along the eastern shore of England, just to check whether the Norse are actually interested in that rainy lump of land? (If Harald can't be bothered to show up, I can see how this scenario would become much more difficult.)

Comment: Did that. He sent a small army of around 2000 near the end of the first year, nothing after that.

Comment: It sounds like one of the patches along the way has changed the way that nations conduct their wars, then. It's too bad that it's kinda ruined this war. Have you tried invading England immediately, since waiting doesn't work? (And does that change how Harald acts?) If you can beat the English troops, and Harald doesn't attack too much, then perhaps you can get a white peace with Harald a while later.

Comment: Doesn't work, England's army is overwhelmingly larger than mine(I get attacked by several armies that are about half of mine in succession, bleeding off troops like mad) and I generally get wiped out. Also, Harold sends armies to invade Normandy as well as keep me occupied in England, eventually dragging the warscore to his favor.

Answer (score 1):

I got CK2 a week back during the Steam sales. I realised that most of the walkthroughs for William the Bastard are no longer valid as they were written back in 2012. As what Paul Marshall had said - the patches had altered the way the AI worked.

Two nights ago I finally managed to become King of England with William (after at many many replays). I think a fair amount of luck is involved plus the fact that I decided to splurge on a Mercenary company (I chose the Great Company for its heavy calavry. )

These are some of the actions I do to maximise my chance of winning.

1. When I first load up the game. I did my usual marriage and betrothal actions for alliances. Currently I am try to get an alliance with King of Norway by marrying William's half-brother (Odo) to his daughter. Then my sons to Denmark, Hungry or HRE. My experience was that immediately after I became King of England, HRE came after me instead of France and that ended my game rather quickly because there was no way I could win a war with HRE after all my troops were attrited.
2. Then I send my Spymaster to York immediately so that I can have a sense of the troop movement. Nine times out of ten, Harold wins against Norway without much losses. From there I keep track of Harold and have a sense when his troops woild arrive at Normandy. Usually it would take 2 months from the start of the game.
3. At the end of the first month, I would hire the merc called Great Company for the hvy calavry as I noticed that Harold does not bring them over to Normandy. What I do then is to wait until Harold lands and seige one of my county. Then I launch an immediate assult at him. The chances of winning is more than even. Thereafter I would keep going after Harold until his troops are depleted before he could flee back to England. This is important because if he gets back with more than 2k troops he is still a threat to you when you start your invasion. As yourself will also be too depleted.
4. At this point I take a look at my own troops. If I have more than 6k troops after dismissing my mercs, I continue with the game as it would give me sufficient troops to start sieging the minor counties in England. The reason I dismissed the mercs is because I found their costs unstainable and I became bankrupt after a few years if I am too slow in forcing the surrender. At this point I would say luck plays a large part. Because if you are lucky and net a few prisoners that gives 100 to 125 gold then keeping the mercs is not a problem.

I hope these opening moves help. Good Luck!